# Changing the middle of a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a list of strings.. each one looks similar to this:

```
"\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"HEADER-\"\r\n\t\t\"NAME\",\"147430\"\r\n\t\t\"REVISION\",\"0000\"\r\n\t\t\"DATE\",\"11/11/10\"\r\n\t\t\"TIME\",\"10:03:47\"\r\n\t\t\"PMABAR\",\"\"\r\n\t\t\"COMMENT\",\"\"\r\n\t\t\"PTPNAME\",\"0805C\"\r\n\t\t\"CMPNAME\",\"0805C\"\r\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"PRTIDDT-\"\r\n\t\t\"PMAPP\",1\r\n\t\t\"PMADC\",0\r\n\t\t\"ComponentQty\",4\r\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"PRTFORM-\"\r\n\t\t\....(more)...."
```

What I am trying to do is keep that entire string BUT... replace the `DATE`, `TIME` and `ComponentQty`.....

I want to place the `date` variable that i have set for the *DATE*, as well as the `DateTime.Now.ToString(""HH:mm:ss")` for the *TIME* ... and a `dictionary[part]` for the *ComponentQty*.  These values would replace like so:

```
"DATE","11/11/10"   with  "DATE","12/06/11"
"TIME","10:03:47"   with  "TIME","10:30:10"
"ComponentQty",4    with  "ComponentQty", 8
```

or something similar...

so the new string would look like this:

```
"\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"HEADER-\"\r\n\t\t\"NAME\",\"147430\"\r\n\t\t\"REVISION\",\"0000\"\r\n\t\t\"DATE\",\"12/06/11\"\r\n\t\t\"TIME\",\"10:30:10"\"\r\n\t\t\"PMABAR\",\"\"\r\n\t\t\"COMMENT\",\"\"\r\n\t\t\"PTPNAME\",\"0805C\"\r\n\t\t\"CMPNAME\",\"0805C\"\r\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"PRTIDDT-\"\r\n\t\t\"PMAPP\",1\r\n\t\t\"PMADC\",0\r\n\t\t\"ComponentQty\",8\r\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"PRTFORM-\"\r\n\t\t\....(more)...."
```

What is the quickest way to do such a thing? I was thinking Regex but I am not too sure on how to go about doing this.  Can anyone help?

### EDIT:

I used just a normal string replace to do it.. but the replaced data will not always have the **statc** date, time, compQty that I have below (11/11/10, 10:03:47, 4)... I need to find a way to make that section not hard coded -- with regex I am assuming..

```
var newDate = "DATE\",\"" + date + "\"";
var newTime = "TIME\",\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\"";
var newCompQTY = "ComponentQty\"," + dictionary[part];

trimmedDataBasePart = trimmedDataBasePart.ToUpper().Replace("DATE\",\"11/11/10", newDate);
trimmedDataBasePart = trimmedDataBasePart.ToUpper().Replace("TIME\",\"10:03:47", newTime);
trimmedDataBasePart = trimmedDataBasePart.ToUpper().Replace("COMPONENTQTY\",4", newCompQTY);
```

I am trying to set a value to a Regex and am not sure how to do so... this is what I was trying... but it obviously does not work because the `var` is not a `string`. any suggestions?

```
var newDate = "DATE\",\"" + date + "\"";
var regexedDate = Regex.Match(trimmedDataBasePart, "DATE\",[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+");
trimmedDataBasePart = trimmedDataBasePart.ToUpper().Replace(regexedDate, newDate);
```

Comment: Your string looks like a whole bunch of lines actually. How big is it, and how many do you have?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yeah the string is a whole bunch of lines. Unfortunately I need the string to look like that and not a whole bunch of strings split by '\n'... :(. I have multiple files so the amount of the strings that I have vary.

Comment: String.Split() and .Join() give you a lot of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(.*\bDATE\b\D*).*?(\\.*\bTIME\b\D*).*?(\\.*\bComponentQty\b\D*)\d+(.*)", "$1NEW_DATE$2NEW_TIME$3NEW_QTY", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Where NEW_DATE should be replaced by your date, NEW_TIME by your time, and NEW_QTY by your new qty.

You can create the replacement string from other variables as you please :)

Well well well, .NET and interpolated variables suck.. If you try to change use "$11" in replacement it thinks it has to use backreference #11 and it fails. Also Regexbuddy had a bug which produced the wrong regex. This is tested and works!

```
string subjectString = "\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"HEADER-\"\r\n\t\t\"NAME\",\"147430\"\r\n\t\t\"REVISION\",\"0000\"\r\n\t\t\"DATE\",\"11/11/10\"\r\n\t\t\"TIME\",\"10:03:47\"\r\n\t\t\"PMABAR\",\"\"\r\n\t\t\"COMMENT\",\"\"\r\n\t\t\"PTPNAME\",\"0805C\"\r\n\t\t\"CMPNAME\",\"0805C\"\r\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"PRTIDDT-\"\r\n\t\t\"PMAPP\",1\r\n\t\t\"PMADC\",0\r\n\t\t\"ComponentQty\",4\r\n\t\"BLOCK\",\"PRTFORM-\"\r\n\t\t....(more)....";
            Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^(.*\bDATE\b\D*).*?(\"".*?\bTIME\b\D*).*?(\"".*?\bComponentQty\b\D*)\d+(.*)$", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            StringBuilder myResult = new StringBuilder();
            Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
            while (matchResults.Success)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < matchResults.Groups.Count; i++)
                {
                    Group groupObj = matchResults.Groups[i];

                    if (groupObj.Success)
                    {
                        myResult.Append(groupObj.Value);
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                myResult.Append("NEW_DATE");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                myResult.Append("NEW_TIME");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                myResult.Append("NEW QTY");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Final Result : \n\n\n{0}", myResult.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
Final Result :



        "BLOCK","HEADER-"
                "NAME","147430"
                "REVISION","0000"
                "DATE","NEW_DATE"
                "TIME","NEW_TIME"
                "PMABAR",""
                "COMMENT",""
                "PTPNAME","0805C"
                "CMPNAME","0805C"
        "BLOCK","PRTIDDT-"
                "PMAPP",1
                "PMADC",0
                "ComponentQty",NEW QTY
        "BLOCK","PRTFORM-"
                ....(more)....
```

By the way you have a falsely escaped dot in your input string. Cheers and have fun! :)

Comment: So if I had 3 variables ***(date, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), dictionary[part])*** how would I change the `"$1NEW_DATE$2NEW_TIME$3NEW_QTY"` ?

Comment: If my memory serves me right : `String.Format("$1{0}$2{1}$3{2}", date, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), dictionary[part]);` and you feed this into the replacement string.

Comment: I like the idea and tried that string. That should work but it seems to not replace anything in the string. I can only assume it has to do with the regex?

Comment: @theNoobGuy I found what the problem is. I am trying to solve it now. Will edit as soon as I have a solution.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it! I was trying to work with: `part = Regex.Replace(part, "DATE\"[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+");` for the date and similar for the time and CompQty..... Look above I will post something I have done and it works.. but maybe you can help me with a regex to make it more versatile

Comment: Haha thank you for noticing the falsely escaped dot ;). Thanks again for your help! it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the way your source string looks, I would use String.Format:

```
string s = String.Format("Date={0}, Name={1}, Quantity={2}", date, name, quantity);
```

The placeholders {0}, {1}, {2} are replaced with the specified arguments which follow.

Answer (score 0):

To make it cleaner I would create a function to parse that string list, and then another function to create such a string list instead of using regexps. I think this will make your code easier to maintain.

```
Dictionary<string, string> Parse(List<string> data)
{
    ...
}

List<string> CreateStringList(Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
    ...
}

List<string> SetValues(List<string> data)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values = Parse(data);
    values["DATE"] = "12/06/11";
    values["TIME"] = "10:30:10";
    values["ComponentQty"] = "4";
    return CreateStringList(values);
}
```